# Delete all rows above a specifc row Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is a sample of the data that I have.

```
    Label | Time
    start | 1.42
    A     | 1.42
    error | 2.21
    C     | 2.24
    C     | 2.24
    error | 2.30
    A     | 2.50
    B     | 2.60
```

Is there anyway I can delete all the rows above the row which has the Label 'error ' including the 'error' row itself (there could be multiple rows with Label 'T') ?
or rather delete all the rows between 'start' and 'error' ?

so that the final output would be

```
    Label | Time
    start | 1.42
    A     | 2.50
    B     | 2.60
```

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Sorry for not posting the desired output. Ive edited the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) for indexes between first `start` and last `error` and then [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
idx = np.r_[df.index[df['Label'] == 'start'][0] + 1:df.index[df['Label'] == 'error'][-1] + 1]
print (idx)
[1 2 3 4 5]

df = df.drop(idx)
print (df)
   Label  Time
0  start  1.42
6      A  2.50
7      B  2.60
```

Another solution:

```
a = (df['Label'] == 'start').shift().fillna(0).cumsum()
b = (df['Label'] == 'error')[::-1].cumsum()
m = a & b
print (df[~m])
   Label  Time
0  start  1.42
6      A  2.50
7      B  2.60
```